# Problem converting EPSG 3035 to EPSG 4326 with GDAL & Python

Tags: python, gdal, epsg

I have following problem:

I want to convert EPSG 3035 coordinates to GPS Latitude & Longitude coordinates (EPSG 4326) via Python.

Therefore I'm using GDAL and following Python Code with EPSG 3035 coordinates: N2628/E4704

```
pointX = 2628
pointY = 4704

# Spatial Reference System
inputEPSG = 3035
outputEPSG = 4326

# create a geometry from coordinates
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(pointX, pointY)

print pointX, pointY

# create coordinate transformation
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(inputEPSG)

outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(outputEPSG)

coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# transform point
point.Transform(coordTransform)

# print point in EPSG 4326
print point.GetX(), point.GetY()
```

unfortunately this returns me a a point somewhere in the South Atlantic, but it should be somewhere in Austria.

The Data Vendor of the EPSG 3035 Coordinates mentions following Reference System of the layer:

> +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this might sound condescending, but rest assure I made this mistake often enough: have you checked that you didn’t mix up X and Y?
Plus: could you please give us an example coordinate pair?

EDIT: sorry, just saw there is an example coordinate pair

Comment: Hi Christoph, I've also tried it with swapping the coordinates -> maybe an interesting hint, that it results in the same point in South Atlantic

Comment: I tried that, too, now … What I find odd, is that your input coordinates are outside of the bounds of the projection (compare http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3035/ ) – I think that’s the actual culprit

Comment: Maybe, but these are exactly the Coordinates I get from my Data Vendor, I've also tried to add between one and three 0s at the end, unfortunately this doesn't bring me to Austria either :(

Comment: if you add `x_0` and `y_0` (false easting, false northing), you at least end up in Europe: 

     `coordTransform.TransformPoint(4321000+4704,3210000+2628)`
`>>> (10.068529554343733, 52.02359886909443, 0.0)`

Comment: ok, that's at least a start ;)

Comment: I mean, I'm not married to using GDAL, if there is another way to get to the coordinates based on the infos I have (North and East offset to x_0 and y_0) it would also be  fine with me

Comment: I don’t think it’s a software thing – can you check back with the data vendor’s specification? Because 4-digit coordinates really don’t look like EPSG:3035 …

Comment: These just aren't valid EPSG 3035 coordinates, go shout at your vendor until they give you some that are. FYI Vienna is at (16.37208, 48.20849) in EPSG 4326 long-lat and (4794151, 2808761) in EPSG:3035.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by 1000 and get the x-y order correct and you end up near Vienna. Here's it done in R:

Make a data frame with the coordinates and an id:

```
> pt2 = data.frame(x=4704000,y=2628000,i=1)
```

Make it spatial by telling it what its coordinates and projection are:

```
> coordinates(pt2)=~x+y
> proj4string(pt2)="+init=epsg:3035"
```

Now transform to epsg 4326 long-lat:

```
> spTransform(pt2,"+init=epsg:4326")
           coordinates i
1 (15.00249, 46.64919) 1
```

Here's Vienna in long-lat:

```
> coordinates(vienna)
       lng      lat
1 16.37208 48.20849
```

Close enough to still be in Austria? I can test that with my geonames interface functions:

```
> GNcountryCode(lng=15.00249, lat=46.64919)

$languages
[1] "de-AT,hr,hu,sl"

$distance
[1] "0"

$countryCode
[1] "AT"

$countryName
[1] "Republic of Austria"
```

I get the same result using your python code:

```
>>> pointX=4704000
>>> pointY=2628000
[...]
>>> print point.GetX(), point.GetY()
15.0024926758 46.6491931687
```

Comment: and that's how it's done ! THX a lot Spacedman, I've tried to add 3 zeros before, and also swapped the order, but I've never tried both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The center of Vienna, in EPSG:3035 coordinate system, is 4,794,100 x 2,808,600
So it seems you have both X and Y reversed, and missing three digits.

Using the proj4 cs2cs utility with your coords in the correct order I get:

```
echo "4704000 2628000" | cs2cs +init=epsg:3035 +to +init=epsg:4326
15d0'8.974"E    46d38'57.095"N 0.000
```

(south west of Graz)